# Nova Relatable Filtering - how to filter users whose company_id matches locations company_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a many to many relationship between users and locations. I want to filter my "attach user" select list to only show users whose `company_id` matches the `company_id` of the location I am currently on. I have created a static function called `relatableUsers` which adds a "where" clause to the query.

```
public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('company_id', ???);
}
```

How do I pull the current location's `company_id` into this where query? If I hard code a `company_id` like below the filter works, so I know this is possible.

```
public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('company_id', 'FA624E60-DD37-11E8-A540-C3C0A709EE15');
}
```

The record information is not stored in the `$request` or the `$query`.

EDIT - adding relationships

User model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

    public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany(Location::class);

}
```

Location model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

    public function users()
{

    return $this->belongstoMany(User::class);

}
```

Company model relationships:

```
public function users()
{

    return $this->hasMany(User::class);

}


public function location()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Location::class);

}
```

Comment: A static function can have no knowledge of a "current" object. Why don't you add another parameter to your function?

Comment: If you add details of the relationships, it's possible someone could give you some help in the form of a `hasManyThrough` relationship.

Comment: @miken32 I have added the relationships, thanks

Comment: What about the `Company` model? How does it relate to both these other models?

Comment: @miken32 added company relationships to users and locations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve the target `Location` from the request like below.

```
public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $location = $request->findResourceOrFail(); // Retrieve the location instance
    return $query->where('company_id', $location->company_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your `locations` and `users` tables both have a `company_id` field, and you want to pull a list of users that have the same `company_id` as the location you're working on. This can be done by filtering the existing relationship method:

```
<?php
class Location extends Model
{
    public function relatableUsers()
    {
        return $this->users()->where("company_id", $this->company_id)->get();
    }
}
```

Note that I call `$this->users()` and not `$this->users`. This return a query builder instance you can alter before talking to the database, rather than pulling all the users and sorting through the collection on the PHP side. Now you can call this on an instance of the `Location` model:

```
<?php
$loc = Location::find($id);
$users = $loc->relatableUsers();
```